# My .gitignore file shows up as an untracked file when I do a git status. Is this normal?

Tags: git, gitignore

So I'm just learning git and initiated a repository. I created a .gitignore file to ignore certain files in my project. Now when I do a git status, although I don't see those other files as untracked files (as I used to before creating a .gitignore), the .gitignore itself shows up as an untracked file in red. Is this normal or am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to hide this? What happens if I do a git add . in the future, will this .gitignore file start getting tracked?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You have to commit `.gitignore` and have it in your repository, otherwise, you'll lose track of it :)

An example, if another friend clones your repository without the `.gitignore`, he will spam your repo with unnecessary files when committing/pushing.

Feel free to `git add .gitignore` and commit ;)

Answer (score 1):

As [Balastrong answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63315381/1256452), you should generally add-and-commit a `.gitignore` file.  (There can be special weird exceptional cases but usually if you're in that situation, you should be putting these items into `.git/info/exclude`.)

The thing to remember here is what *untracked file* really means, and how this interacts with Git and commits.

#### Git stores commits

The reason Git exists is to store *commits*.  It's actually the commits that form the branches, and that *are* the history.  Each commit stores a complete snapshot of *every* file that Git knows about, in a special, read-only, Git-only, de-duplicated form.  This de-duplication trick takes quick care of the fact that *most* commits mostly just re-use the files from a previous commit: that way, your Git repository does not grow huge even though each commit has a full (but shared!) copy of every file.

#### The files you work with are *copies*

Given that nothing inside the commit can ever be changed—this is a consequence of the hashing trick that Git uses to number commits (and, internally, the files stored inside each commit)—this means that the files that you see and work with, when you do work in a repository, are *not* the files stored in the commits!  Instead, they are copies, extracted out of some commit, and turned back into ordinary (not-read-only, not-compressed-and-de-duplicated) files.

These copies are in your *working tree* or *work-tree* (two terms for the same thing; Git mostly uses the longer spelling, but I like the shorter one).  The work-tree is, technically at least, separate from the repository.<sup>1</sup>  Git has a mode, called a *bare repository*, in which there is no work-tree at all, and has the ability to add more work-trees to a repository, using `git worktree add`.

Because of this technical distinction, your work-tree is *yours*, to do with as you wish.  You can create files in it that Git *doesn't* know about.

---

<sup>1</sup>In a normal, non-bare repository, the repository itself is in a `.git` directory at the top level of your work-tree.  When using `git worktree add`, the added work-trees get a `.git` file containing the path name of the repository, so that Git can find it.

---

#### The *index* or *staging area*

The way Git keeps track of the files that Git knows about—that is, the files that are in your work-tree right now, that will go into the *next* commit you might make—is to use a thing that Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or sometimes—rarely these days—the *cache*.  These names all refer to the same thing.  The name "index" is because it's (mostly) stored in `.git/index`; the name *staging area* refers to how it functions.

What's in the index is a bit complicated, in part by its multiple roles: it takes on an expanded role during conflicted merges, for instance.  But at *its* heart, the index is really just a list of files, in Git's read-only, compressed, Git-only, and de-duplicated form, that are *ready to go into the next commit*.

In effect, then, the index holds a *third* copy—but de-duplicated, so that it's never an actual *copy*—of each of your files.  The three copies of each file are therefore:

- The copy from the current commit, that Git extracted when you ran `git clone` and/or `git checkout`.  This file cannot be changed, because it's inside a commit.
- The copy in the index.  It's in the read-only format, but you *can* change it—or rather *replace* it entirely—because it's *not* inside a commit.
- The copy in your work-tree.  This one is *yours*, to do with as you will.

Whenever you change the work-tree copy, the index copy *isn't changed yet:* it still matches the copy in the commit (and thanks to the de-duplication, literally just shares that copy).  To update the index copy, you must run `git add` on the file.  This tells Git: *make the index copy match the work-tree copy*.  Git will now compress, Git-ify, and de-duplicate the work-tree contents, turning the file into something that is ready to go into the *next* commit, and update the index with that copy.

**This is *why* the index is called the *staging area:* it holds each file that will go into the *next* commit, in a form ready to be committed.  This is how Git knows which files to commit.**  The index (or staging area) holds the copies of the files that will be in the next commit.

An *untracked file* is, quite simply, a file that is not in Git's index *right now*.  That means that if you make a new commit, that file won't be in the new commit.

You can add a file to Git's index any time, with `git add`.  You can remove a file from Git's index any time, with `git rm --cached` or `git rm`.<sup>2</sup>  These operations alter the index / staging-area contents, so that the *next* commit has different files—a different snapshot—in it.

---

<sup>2</sup>The difference between these two is that `git rm` will remove the index copy *and* the work-tree copy, while `git rm --cached` will remove only the index copy.

---

#### `git checkout` / `git switch` fills both the index and your work-tree

When you use `git checkout` or (since Git 2.23) `git switch` to select a commit, you are telling Git: *Hey Git, fill in your index to match the commit I'm checking out, and adjust my work-tree to match.*  This will, if necessary, *remove* some files from your work-tree, or create new files in your work-tree.  So while your work-tree *is* yours, remember that some Git commands literally tell Git to modify your work-tree.

The details here can get pretty tricky, but what's in your index at the time you use these commands affects what happens.  In particular, if you use `git rm --cached` to make a file become untracked, and then check out some other commit that doesn't have the file, Git *won't* remove your untracked work-tree copy.  If you have the file *tracked*—in both Git's index and your work-tree—and you check out some other commit that doesn't have the file, Git *will* remove both its index copy and your work-tree copy.

#### The index and work-tree are never cloned

When you use `git clone` to copy a repository, this copies the *commits* from the `origin` repository to your new clone.  You do not get to see their Git's index, nor their work-tree (if they even have one: the repositories on hosting systems like GitHub and Bitbucket are generally bare clones).

The only *files* you have, then, after cloning, are the ones that were in some commit.  After a fresh clone you won't have untracked files, because `git clone` only got the *commits* (and then, at the end, ran `git checkout master` or whatever was appropriate, to fill in Git's index and your work-tree).

This is why, in general, you will commit each `.gitignore` file: if the file should be quietly left untracked in *your* work-tree, it probably should be quitely left untracked in someone else's work-tree when *they* clone, too.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the file `.gitignore` you can add ".gitignore" to your `.gitignore`. Like this:

```
echo .gitignore >> .gitignore
```

Comment: I'm not sure this was the answer the OP was looking for ... :D:D